# Will spring XD run a module on multiple containers

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I am pretty new to Spring XD and would like to know  more about the internals of it.

I read on the docs that a module would be deployed onto a container and admin would we governing the containers and if any of the containers fail the modules deployed in the failed container would be redeployed onto one of the running containers.

So does this mean that if I write a custom module that would always run as a single instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of instances deployed is controlled by the [deployment manifest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#deployment-manifest), specifically:

> **module.[modulename].count**
>
> The number of module instances (see above).

You can control which container(s) a module is deployed to with

> **module.[modulename].criteria**